# Date.compareTo(Date) not working

Tags: java, android, date, compare

I am writing an app scenario, where need to match between two date if there are same or not and that I am trying to achieve using `Date.compareTo()`. But it never return 0 as API said for equal date.

I am getting these dates from `Caledar.getTime()` but it never

I checked with print to both date object and even they are returning same string.

```
Sat Nov 15 14:17:41 GMT+05:30 2014, Sat Nov 15 14:17:41 GMT+05:30 2014
```

Any suggestion, how to check date object if they are equal or not.

Comment: did you check if the milliseconds are the same?

Comment: set both of your dates seconds and milliseconds to zero..

Comment: print both dates as long using date.getTime() and see the difference.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_compareto.htm

Comment: @Rolfツ i cheked with same to print both date object as an string...and it returning me same.

Comment: Those prints do not contain milliseconds so they could still be different.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I checked with it ..but in my case it not returning same result. In given link they are checking with provided yy/mm/dd..so might be it's working there.

Comment: post code its working ...........

Comment: @Rolfツ so u saying Calendar.compare() work basis on millisecond as well?

Comment: YES @Rolfツ they are different...so then how to compare date object ?

Comment: @Shubh That depends on what is an equal date for you. Different milliseconds means different date.

Comment: @PedroOliveira yes..true..I am using deprecated API and it's working in current case...I get year/month/date from calendar object and create date object and compared...and it's working.

Comment: A java.util.Date resolves to a fraction of a second, [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), rather than whole seconds. The default implementation of the `toString` method does not show this fraction of a second. Tip: Use Joda-Time or java.time libraries instead of java.util.Date/.Calendar.

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot to check if the dates milliseconds are the same.

This is the source code of the compareTo method.

```
public int compareTo(Date anotherDate) {
    long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
    long anotherTime = getMillisOf(anotherDate);
    return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));
}
```

As you can see this method compares two dates using milliseconds as "time step".

---

**Code for old API:**

This code checks if two days are the same. (Without hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds)

```
Date date1; //Your initial date
Date date2; //Your initial second date

//Remove hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds by creating new "clean" Date objects
Date compare1 = new Date(date1.getYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDay());
Date compare2 = new Date(date2.getYear(), date2.getMonth(), date2.getDay());

if(compare1.compareTo(compare2) == 0){

}
```

But I suggest you don't use Date for this task. Because the getYear, getMonth etc. methods are deprecated I suggest you take a look at newer API's like [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) and [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

---

**Code for new API**

This code checks if two days are the same including hours and minutes. But without seconds and milliseconds.

```
Date date1;
Date date2;

Calendar compareCalendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar compareCalendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
compareCalendar1.setTime(date1);
compareCalendar2.setTime(date2);


//Set for both calendars the seconds and milliseconds to 0
compareCalendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
compareCalendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

compareCalendar2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
compareCalendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if(compareCalendar1.compareTo(compareCalendar2) == 0){

}
```

Comment: yes Rofl I tried same and it's working..but since it's to create Date Constructor is deprecated..so there should be other way to get it.

Comment: I made a small typo in the if statement. It works now, tested on a real device.

Comment: Try setting the minutes and hours also to 0 if you just want to compare days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64787/discussion-between-shubh-and-rolf-).

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand compare scenario :

```
Date date1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Date date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

date1.compareTo(date2) >> -1
```

**AND**

```
Date date3 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Date date4 = date3;

date3.compareTo(date4) >> 0
```